# CHMOD permission denied on SMB share

Tags: linux, server-message-block, cifs, chmod

I'm mounting an SMB/CIFS share on my CentOS 6.4 server using /etc/fstab as follows:

## Mount windows share to /mnt/mywebsite

//10.1.1.4/mywebsite /mnt/mywebsite   cifs    username=httpd,password=topsecret,uid=apache,gid=apache    0       0

I then issue mount -a and I see that my mount is created and the owner is apache:apache.

I can create files and directories just fine but if I try and do a chmod on files. For example:

mkdir test
chmod 755 test

I get the following error:
chmod: changing permissions of `test': Permission denied

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this. Is there an SELINUX policy blocking me? Do I need to add some additional parameters in my /etc/fstab?

I tried doing grep http /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why and I'm not seeing SELINUX blocking me.

Thanks
Brad